# Find: exclude external hard drive from search

Tags: bash, find

Is there a way to perform a find command on my whole computer, excluding external hard drives? I've been using the find command to search for junk left over from uninstalled software, like (from the top of the directory):

```
sudo find -iname . "*badexample*"
```

I'm confident there's nothing I'm looking for on my external drive. I suppose I could simply disconnect it before doing the find, but I'm curious how I might specify such an exclusion with bash. I'm also a little confused about where the external drive is located in the directory as well; /Volumes contains an alias that points to the drive, but it looks (using Get Info in Finder) like it points to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

`-mount  Don’t descend directories on other filesystems.`

Use this to see it yourself:

`man find | less -p "-mount"`

Of course this will prevent find from descending into ANY other filesystems, not just the one USB drive you are attempting to exclude.

Alternatively, you can do this.  It won't save time and it WILL still search the USB drive, but will not display those particular results:

`find / -name "badpattern" | grep -v "/path/to/USB_DRIVE"`

Comment: I had to do a little digging (version of find on my computer uses `-x` instead of `-mount`), but this worked. Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: Many Linux programs use -x (like du for example).  The find command also allows -xdev in addition to -mount.  They both do the same thing.